# keyError in Flask application using Stripe's checkout

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I am making a simple flask application using stripe's checkout.
just like in:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/flask
- app.py

but I am getting error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tusharrajput/Desktop/app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
'secret_key': os.environ['SECRET_KEY'],
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I have my secret_key and purchasable_key, but i don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the SECRET_KEY as Environment variable because you are using `os.environ`

#### Setting on UNIX

```
export SECRET_KEY=whatever  # for Bourne, bash, and related shells
```

OR

```
setenv SECRET_KEY whatever  # for csh and related shells
```

#### Setting up on Windows under "Environment Variables"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `SECRET_KEY` and `PUBLISHABLE_KEY` [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) to make it work.